# How to DRY up shared scopes for Mongoid models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a few Mongoid model classes that all have a :datetime field. I would like to query these models to find out records that fall under today's date. The query would look like this:

```
scope today, where(:datetime.gt => DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, :datetime.lt => DateTime.now.end_of_day)
```

Currently, the above scope code are duplicated within all the model classes. How do I dry this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples thing is:

```
module TimeDepedentent
  field :datetime

  scope today, where(:datetime.gt => DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, :datetime.lt => DateTime.now.end_of_day)

  scope yesterday ...
  scope one_month_ago ...
end

class MyModel
  include TimeDepedentent
end
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699343/rails-is-that-possible-to-define-named-scope-in-a-module