# Rails - Creating global named scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have model A, B, and C which needs the same scope.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699343/rails-is-that-possible-to-define-named-scope-in-a-module) which mention about creating a module and include it:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Scopes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :disabled, where(:disabled => true)
  end

  module ClassMethods
   ...
  end
end
```

But then it doesn't explain on where to put and how to include.

I tried putting the code above in `config/my_scopes.rb` and include it in my `application_controller.rb` as follow:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Scopes
  ...
end
```

I got **Routing Error** saying this:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Scopes
```

I'm quite new to Rails so I'm not sure what cause it. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should require file like `require 'concerns/scopes.rb'` in Rails 3.

Also you scope is for `ActiveRecord`, and you are including it in controller, that won't work I guess. You should do it like this:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Base
    include Scopes
  end
end
```

I'm not sure where you should place this file (and will it work or not:)).

Or maybe:

```
class ActiveRecord
  include Scopes
end
```

And require this file in ApplicationController

Comment: Thanks! Got it, and one more fix: it should be included to a Model instead of Controller.

Comment: Yes, I just fixing my answer about it.