# Is it possible to define a global scope on Activerecord::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, named-scope

I know I can make a module that defines a scope and include this module in a model, following, for example, [this question's discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699343/rails-is-that-possible-to-define-named-scope-in-a-module).

But say I have 100 models, all of which have `created_at` fields. I want to have a scope reading from `created_at`, but I do not want to manually include the module in all the models. I want to define a scope **globally** for all models.

Seeing how all models inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, I keep looking for ways to define a scope there, but my efforts with using concerns end up with errors.

```
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord
```

Comment: That's not a good idea. You should not modify ActiveRecord::Base or you will increase the risk of conflicts. The right approach is to include the module in your models.

Comment: The `scoped` portion in that other answer was throwing me off, since it is deprecated in Rails4. Put an updated answer there.